# EF Core: What's the most optimized way to "refetch" an entity in order to get access to FK objects during a creation of a new object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a new entity and then aggregate properties on FK objects then save them to the newly created object.  Think of populating a keywords field on the object to drive a google like search.

Currently, I've found that the only way to do this is to Add the new entity, call context.SaveChanges(), fetch the newly created entity with all of the include statements, and then use the fetched entity to create the keyword field.

This seems inefficient considering the number of DB hits that need to happen.

Other ORMs have the capability of refetching on save.

What is the most optimized way to handle this in EF Core?

Comment: Wouldnt this essentially just be 3 queries hitting the database? Is that really so critically bad? essentially a re fetch on save is generally implementing the same select query to get the object again, just combined into the save.. resulting in the same amount of queries, just present to you differently?

Comment: I think it's the having to call save twice that seems inefficient to me.  I've noticed that the FKs don't populate on the entity when Add is called.   If they did, I would be able to eliminate the refetch and the 2nd save.  It's not horribly inefficient but it seems like I'm missing some other functionality that would make it better.  If this is the best way, I can live with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this syntax?

```
context.Entry(blog)
    .Collection(b => b.Posts)
    .Load();

context.Entry(blog)
    .Reference(b => b.Owner)
    .Load();
```

You can load the references onto an existing Entity that way, if I'm understanding the process you're describing correctly.

See the docs for reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading

Comment: Boom!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Using the .Entry().Reference().Load() methods, I now have the ability to load the FK objects to then use later to populate the aggregate field and save the context once.  Thank you!  Very helpful!